# How to replace newlines between brackets

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, logfile

I have log file similar to this format

```
test {
seq-cont {
                        0,
                        67,
                        266
                        },
                grp-id 505
        }
}
test{
        test1{
                val
        }
}
```

Here is the echo command to produce that output

`$ echo -e "test {\nseq-cont {\n\t\t\t0,\n\t\t\t67,\n\t\t\t266\n\t\t\t},\n\t\tgrp-id 505\n\t}\n}\ntest{\n\ttest1{\n\t\tval\n\t}\n}\n"`

Question is how to remove all whitespace between `seq-cont {` and the next `}` that may be multiple in the file.

I want the output to be like this. Preferably use sed to produce the output.

```
test{seq-cont{0,67,266},
                       grp-id 505
        }
}
test{
        test1{
                val
        }
}
```

Efforts by OP: Here is the one somewhat worked but not exactly what I wanted:

```sh
sed ':a;N;/{/s/[[:space:]]\+//;/}/s/}/}/;ta;P;D' logfile
```

Comment: Why have newlines been removed after `266` but not after `505`, despite both being  "between brackets"? Is it only for input "between inner-most brackets"

Comment: Yes that's right. Between First matching open and close brackets

Comment: @RamananT, also please do add your tried code as your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: Try `echo -e "test {seq-cont {0,67,266},\n\t\tgrp-id 505\n\t}\n}\ntest{\n\ttest1{\n\t\tval\n\t}\n}\n"`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Here is the one somewhat worked but not exactly what I wanted:
sed ':a;N;/{/s/[[:space:]]\+//;/}/s/}/}/;ta;P;D'

Comment: @RamananT, Thanks for letting know. Its always recommended to add efforts in your question, as of now I have added your tried command, kindly do always add your tried code as your efforts in your question, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using `gnu-awk` with a custom `RS` regex that matches `{` and closing `}`:

```sh
awk -v RS='{[^}]+}' 'NR==1 {gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "", RT)} {ORS=RT} 1' file

test {seq-cont{0,67,266},
                grp-id 505
        }
}
test{
        test1{
                val
        }
}
```

Here:

- `NR==1 {gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, "", RT)}`: For the first record replace all whitespaces (including line breaks) with empty string.
- `{ORS=RT}`: Set `ORS` to whatever text we captured in `RS`

PS: Remove `NR==1` if you want to do this for entire file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that much easier with `perl`:

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\s+(seq-cont\s*\{[^}]*\})/$1=~s|\s+||gr/ge' logfilepath
```

The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp the file into a single string, `-i` saves changes inline, `\s+(seq-cont\s*\{[^}]*\})` regex matches one or more whitespaces, then captures into Group 1 (`$1`) `seq-cont`, zero or more whitespaces, and then a substring between the leftmost `{` and the next `}` char (`[^}]*` matches zero or more chars other than `}`) and then all one or more whitespace character chunks (matched with `\s+`) are removed from the whole Group 1 value (`$1`) (this second inner replacement is enabled with `e` flag). All occurrences are handled due to the `g` flag (next to `e`).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/muoobK):

```
#!/bin/bash
s=$(echo -e "test {\nseq-cont {\n\t\t\t0,\n\t\t\t67,\n\t\t\t266\n\t\t\t},\n\t\tgrp-id 505\n\t}\n}\ntest{\n\ttest1{\n\t\tval\n\t}\n}\n")
perl -0777 -pe 's/\s+(seq-cont\s*\{[^}]*\})/$1=~s|\s+||gr/ge' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
test {seq-cont{0,67,266},
        grp-id 505
    }
}
test{
    test1{
        val
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Tested and written in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= '
match($0,/{\nseq-cont {\n[^}]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `RS` capability to set it to null. Then using `match` function of `awk` to match everything between `seq-cont {` to till next occurrence of `}`. Removing all spaces, new lines in matched value. Finally printing all the values including newly edited values to get expected output mentioned by OP.